# Firebase .setCurrentScreen for view-based apps

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

My app is build with single `Activity` and every screen is simple `View`.

```
Activity(stack)
    - screen1
    - screen2
```

I log my current screen like this `firebaseAnalytics.setCurrentScreen(activity, screenName, null)`
where `activity` is a single activity for every screen and `screenName` is name of actually screen represented by `View`.

And this is what do I see in my Firebase dashboard :(
[image]

It prints out activity class instead of screen name! Of course, I can navigate to details and switch from `Screen classes` to `Screen names` but I must do it every time I open Firebase Dashboard!

How can log my actual `Screen class` (MainScreenView) instead of one stupid activity `AppActivity`.

Is there any way to overcome this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use that 3rd parameter of the `setCurrentScreen` method instead of just sending null. [Further reading](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics#setCurrentScreen(android.app.Activity,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

```
firebaseAnalytics.setCurrentScreen(activity, screenName, "YourViewClassNameHere")
```